# Open pop-up, stay on top but not on focus

Tags: javascript, html, popup, catia

I made a pop-up that allow some users to run Scripts (CATScripts actually) from a convenient, small interface. Scripts run in Catia, and they need 32 links, provided in my pop up (ugly but useful you know?)

It works fine, but the pop-ups keep getting hidden by other windows.

So I add this to my header (found in this website):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    window.onblur = function() {
        setTimeout('self.focus()',1);
    }
</script>
```

Which works, but then gets annoying: once you click on link in my pop-up, it stays focused, and prevent users, say, typing a comment on an other program.

So my need would be: bring my pop-up to front, "always on top", but without the "focus".
Is that possible?

P.S.: Due to my company limitations, and code implementation, this only runs on IE (it's completely blocked and not accessible on other browsers).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does something in your setup restrict you from using a "popup" in the same window in a div which you can place on top?

Comment: Yes actually, because all the other windows used are outside of the browser: catia (3d design software) is the main one, and then many tools, and many windows, which makes a mess on the screen. Depending on the solution I could find, I intend to make the "do not hide" function an option, so I don't add in the mess for those who don't need it, but from recent feedback it was useful for many. I could go to the solution of an external software, but, again I'm limited by company rules, so I'm not for this solution!